# generate PDF from command line does not insert references

Tags: compiling

I'm trying to make a function that compiles my latex documents from the command line. My problem is that the references never show up on the first run so I usually end up running this function twice... it's usually not a big deal unless I'm working on a large document.

Anyone know why the references might not be showing up first time through?

I based my function off what I think TexMaker is doing: Options/Configure TexMaker/Quick Build

```
PdfLaTeX + Bib(la)tex + PdfLaTeX (x2) + View Pdf
```

any thoughts?

```
generatePDF() {
GREEN='\033[1;32m'
NC='\033[0m' # No color                                                                                                

    echo -e "${GREEN}Running pdflatex ${NC}"
    pdflatex -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode -enable-write18 -shell-escape $1.tex

    # TODO: needs more error testing for next commands...                                                              
    echo -e "${GREEN}Running bib(la)tex...${NC}"
    bibtex $1.aux

    echo -e "${GREEN}Running pdflatex again...${NC}"
    pdflatex -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode -enable-write18 -shell-escape $1.tex

    echo -e "${GREEN}Opening pdf... ${NC}"
    gnome-open $1.pdf
}

cleanPDFdir() {
GREEN='\033[1;32m'
NC='\033[0m' # No color                                                                                                
    echo -e "${GREEN}Removing auxiliary files...${NC}"
    rm -v $1.pdf
    rm -v $1.aux
    rm -v $1.bbl
    rm -v $1.bbg
    rm -v $1.log
    rm -v $1.synctex*
}

alias pdfmake='generatePDF'
alias pdfclean='cleanPDFdir'
```

I run the function by just specifying the main file's name without the extension:

```
pdfmake my_tex_file
```

additional info from comments:
I'm using emacs so started putting this script together so I could quickly compile like I did when using TexMaker's quick build.

The individual commands I just found here and on Stack Overflow so I don't really understand what each is doing.

Comment: The references (`.bib` or `\ref` - like) **always** need two runs. I suggest to use a `Makefile` and ordinary `make`. You should also mention that this a shell-script?

Comment: specifying the separate independent steps within the main `.tex` file with `arara` might also be a possibility.  (`texdoc arara` or go to http://www.texdoc.net/ and search for `arara`.)

Comment: why do you want a script that runs pdflatex three times and bibtex as well?: you should hardly ever need to do that, after a typical edit you just need to run pdflatex once and not bibtex at all.

Comment: You are reinventing the wheel: There are a lot of programs that solve your problem, e.g. [tag:arara] or `make` or [tag:latexmk] or ...

Comment: Your script doesn't do what you say it does. It does not run pdfLaTeX twice after running BibTeX. Hence, one run will not be enough to resolve the citations. If you were using Biblatex with Biber, it would (usually) be sufficient. But BibTeX needs an additional run (at least).

Comment: Why both `-enable-write18` and `-shell-escape`?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle, That's what TexMaker's Quick Build says it's doing so just made my scrip emulate that. I also didn't realize I could just run pdflatex for most updates. thanks!

Comment: @MartinSchröder I didn't know about those, thanks, I'll look into them.

Comment: @cfr stupid error on my part, I didn't misunderstood the (2x) in the TexMaker Quickbuild dialog. I'll update my script to actually run it twice more.

Comment: you only need to re-run bibtex if you have added a new `\cite` and it's unlikely you do that every edit, and you only need to run pdflatex more than once if the cross referencing information has changed since  last time, which normally isn't the case or doesn't matter while previewing as you are going to run pdflatex again in after the next edit anyway.

Comment: also do you really want nonstopmode  when running from the commandline? editors do that so they can parse the log and highlight errors etc but from the commandline seems more natural just to stop at the error so you can fix it and re-run.

Answer (score 4):

try `latexmk my_tex_file`  or
`latexmk -xelatex my_tex_file`

Comment: And what should it do? Please do not only tell a command, explain it! As it stands this is more a comment than an answer.

Comment: Well, people can just look up what latexmk is. If the user is using texlive, I'd say this is a good solution, as I'm a heavy latexmk user myself.